# How large is the download for the .NET 4.0 client profile?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-client-profile

I've seen numbers about the [full install size](http://blogs.msdn.com/jgoldb/archive/2010/04/12/what-s-new-in-net-framework-4-client-profile-rtm.aspx) of the framework, but my Google-fu has failed me when it comes to how large the upgrade download will be. For instance, for a user who has 2.0 installed, how much will they have to download to upgrade to 4.0CP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

41 MB as shown on the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e5ad0459-cbcc-4b4f-97b6-fb17111cf544).

Update: It has to download all 41MB no matter what.  4.0 is not an upgrade to 2.0 like 3.0 and 3.5 were.  It's a standalone version.